# Deque container of C++ STL

Tags: c++

I have certain doubts regarding deque container in C++.

1. What is the difference between resize()[C98] and shrink_to_fit()[C11]?
2. I have learnt that when a deque becomes full, it allocates a small chunk of extra memory for adding new elements to it. I want to know the size of this memory chunk that is being allocated newly.

Thanks.

Comment: If you haven't, look at a [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/shrink_to_fit). The first line says it all: *Requests the removal of unused capacity.* Anyway, this isn't guaranteed to be implemented in a particular way as your second question suggests. It's up to the implementer to choose exactly how best to implement it. Again, the same reference for `std:deque`: *typical implementations use a sequence of individually allocated fixed-size arrays*

Answer (score 1):

### Part 1

A deque has 2 relevant attributes: **capacity**, and **size**. Capacity is the number of elements that we've allocated memory for. Size is the current number of elements in the container.

`resize()`, will usually just modify the **size** of the container to the expected value. The **capacity** will usually not change.

`shrink_to_fit()` will request that the deque release extra memory such that the internal **capacity** is reduced to be equal to the **size** of the container.

Before C++11, there was no obvious way to request that a container reduce its **capacity**.

### Part 2

This is implementation defined.

Comment: Wait, deques don't have capacities (only vectors do).

Comment: @Brian: It has a capacity, we just can't query it.

Comment: The mention of `capacity` as a field is confusing, because vector doesn't have any such member.

Comment: Given a typical implementation, you could think of the capacity as the combined storage of all allocated array chunks.

Comment: @juanchopanza: std::deque::shrink_to_fit says: _It is a non-binding request to reduce capacity to size().__ A deque has a capacity, and it has a size. We can query the size using size(), and we have no capability to query the capacity. If you have a better word than __field__, I'd be glad to swap it. But none are coming to mind.

Comment: It actually says "a non binding request to reduce memory use..."

Comment: @sharth, Perhaps attribute? Anyway, in the context of standard containers, what exactly is the difference between capacity and memory use? To me, they're synonyms.

Comment: @sharth, I already died when I found one thing wrong on there that was correct on the site that shall not be named. It got promptly fixed at least.